# HTML table - minimize width of some columns while retaining width of others. Mixed with colspans

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have pretty simple table showing prices. It looks like this

[image]

Now I want to do something which isn't that simple. I want to make it look better by making all the numbers align to the right while retaining alignment of `od` and `Kč`. In other words, in this case I want the last number `60` to shift to the right to align with the longer numbers above.

The only way that came to my mind is to split each column into 3 columns containing each "word" `od`, `the number itself` and `Kč` and make the middle one align to the right. Also I need to minimize the width of the first two in the triad.

In other words, I want to split the column into 3, having the total width of 25% of the table and the first two columns should be as small as possible and the last column with `Kč` should take as much of the width as possible.

This way I can align the number to the right while making the illusion of the whole text being aligned to the left.

Here's the over-simplified code of what I tried to do:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <th>Ceník</th>
         <th colspan="3">Krátké vlasy</th>
         <th colspan="3">Podlouhlé vlasy</th>
         <th colspan="3">Dlouhé vlasy</th>
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <td>Střih</td>

         <td>od</td>
         <td>130</td>
         <td>Kč</td>

         <td>od</td>
         <td>280</td>
         <td>Kč</td>

         <td>od</td>
         <td>250</td>
         <td>Kč</td>
     </tr>

     <!-- OTHER ROWS HERE -->
</table>
```

and the CSS styles

```
th, td { width: 25% }
tr td:nth-child(2),
tr td:nth-child(3),
tr td:nth-child(5),
tr td:nth-child(6),
tr td:nth-child(8),
tr td:nth-child(9) { width: 1px; }
```

I tried to do just this to see how it will work out. It didn't affect the width of the columns at all. The columns are still evenly spaced. I don't understand what's wrong with this code. Any ideas?

Also if you have better idea how to align the numbers in the first place, feel free to share it. I understand that this is pretty much hack but I don't know any better. Thanks.

Comment: The columns are still evenly spaced. You're speaking about the `th` or `td`?

Comment: Both. Since `th` has `colspan="3"` they all have 25% width. On the other hand, `td` are evenly spaced according to that. The triads have 25% total width each but are evenly spaced, while I want the first 2 columns in each triad to have minimal width and the last one to take majority of space.

Comment: I don't understand the requirements, I have made an attempt to fix the issue in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9poessty/1/).

Comment: @doveyg You set the last column in the triad to have minimal width. That's the opposite of what I need. I need the two other columns to have minimal width and the last one to be as wide as possible.

Comment: @doveyg Also what's the point of setting the default width of the cell to 15%?

Comment: [Flipped it around then](http://jsfiddle.net/9poessty/3/). Why 15%? It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to fill in spaces to align the numbers. You can use [figure spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_space) to make sure they are as wides as the digits (if the font supports it). Also set the [OpenType feature of tabular figures in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings), just be sure (again, only works if the font supports it).

```css
table {
  font-feature-settings: "tnum";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Ceník</th>
    <th>Krátké vlasy</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Střih</td>

    <td>od &#8199;&#8199;&#8199;1 Kč</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Střih</td>

    <td>od &#8199;&#8199;60 Kč</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Střih</td>

    <td>od &#8199;160 Kč</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Střih</td>

    <td>od 1160 Kč</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an excellent place for pseudo-elements.

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
thead {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white
}
td {
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
tr td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
thead td:not(:first-child) {
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}
tbody td:not(:first-child):after {
  content: ' $';
}
tbody td:not(:first-child):before {
  content: 'From';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Discounted Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Socks (pack of 50 pair)</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ties (each)</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```